# BeautifulSoup - Parsing the file for numeric values

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Want to parse out 1 & 1999 from tags:

```
'''
<li><a **href="/1/"**>|&lt;</a></li>
<li><a accesskey="p" **href="/1999/"** rel="prev">&lt; Prev</a></li>
<li><a href="//c.xkcd.com/random/comic/">Random</a></li>
<li><a accesskey="n" href="#" rel="next">Next &gt;</a></li>
<li><a href="/">&gt;|</a></li>
'''
```

What I tried:
BeautifulSoup Code used to parse HTML:

```
  for li in soup_obj.find_all('li'):
        for tag in li.find_all(re.compile("\/[0-9]+\/")):
            print(tag)
            print(tag['href'])
```

Steps:

1) Take out the (li)

2) Assert (href) is true

Answer (score 1):

Search for the `href` value from start, no need for nested searches

```
for anchor in soup_obj.find_all(href=re.compile(r'/\d+/')):
    print(anchor.name)
    print(anchor['href'])
```

Comment: I assumed OP added `**` to the html as indicators of what he wants, if you parse it as-is those will be errors and not added thus will not show up on `find_all`

Comment: well if this is the case then your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` like this example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

a = '''
<li><a **href="/1/"**>|&lt;</a></li>
<li><a accesskey="p" **href="/1999/"** rel="prev">&lt; Prev</a></li>
<li><a href="//c.xkcd.com/random/comic/">Random</a></li>
<li><a accesskey="n" href="#" rel="next">Next &gt;</a></li>
<li><a href="/">&gt;|</a></li>
'''

soup = bs(a, 'html.parser')
nums = [k['**href'].strip('/') for k in soup.find_all('a', {'**href': re.compile(r'/\d+/')})]

print(nums)
```

Output:

```
['1', '1999']
```